# JQuery Syntax for function mean

Tags: javascript

What does this Jquery Syntax mean ?

```
!function ($) {

//function code here

}
```

The function starts with a '!' and also doese`nt have a name.

can i get an explanation ?

Comment: It's not just a duplicate ... there are no "calling parentheses" after the function body, are there?

Comment: btw, this is plain Javascript and not specifically jQuery

Comment: @devnull69 — Then it does absolutely nothing. It's a function statement that is immediately discarded. Assuming that the `()` are just missing from the question is reasonable.

Comment: @Quentin: it's still a function expression, but yes it has no side effects ;)